# Magento 2: how to solve unique constraint violation in SalesSequence

Tags: magento2

Magento 2.2.4, PHP 7.0.30.

While running setup:upgrade command in SSH, a list of modules appear then I get:

> Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':
>   Running data recurring...Unique constraint violation found

Then the upgrade seems to stop. How do I identify the data causing the unique constraint violation? I have checked some log files in var/logs and some tables containing "sequence" in the database using PHPMyAdmin, but there is probably a better way.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can run the following command php bin/magento setup:db-data:upgrade

It would be mostly the unique value issue in table "cym_sales_sequence_meta" for the field "sequence_table". You can remove the values or empty the table and run the setup upgrade again. The issue will be sorted.

Comment: Sorry, should have closed this issue a long time ago. The problem was indeed the sales_sequece_meta table, because I have a website with 2 store views and I played with this table so that my invoice numbers are sequential for accounting. I run a SQL query to 'fix' the data, then run setup:upgrade, then run another SQL query to revert to the data I need. A bit cumbersome, but does the trick.